# Extracting the "positive" part of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Let $p$ be an even polynomial of degree $2n$ such that all its roots are real; hence, it can be written as $p(x)=q(x)q(-x)$, where $q$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ will all roots non-negative. I am interested in finding $q$ given $p$.

Assuming that we have a certain knowledge about $p$ (say, its explicit expression, or a linear ODE whose solution is $p$, etc.), how can we "transfer" it to $q$? In other words, can we say anything about $q$?

Equivalently, $r(x)=p(\sqrt{x})$ is a polynomial whose roots are non-negative and that are squares of the roots of $q$. Is there any reasonably constructive transformation that takes square roots of the zeros of a polynomial, in terms of its coefficients, generating function, accompanying matrix, etc.?

I know that the question might sound vague, but so far I have found nothing at all in this regard. So, any information or consideration could be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by the first sentence?  Is it supposed to apply to $x^2+1$?

Comment: Well, for polynomials of degree 2 I know how to do it. But if $p(x)=x^6-14 x^4+49 x^2-36$, then $q(x)=x^3-6 x^2+11 x-6$. We can see it if we know the roots: $p(x)=(x^2-9) (x^2-4) (x^2-1)$, while $q(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$. Otherwise, how do we get $q$ from $p$, without knowing the roots, only coefficients?

Comment: Btw @Ben, maybe I mistunderstood your comment, sorry. We know that $p$ has only real roots. This is not the case of $x^2+1$.

Comment: i believe that the transformation you are looking at is closely related to the inverse Graeffe transform of a polynomial, see e.g. http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2016/07/11/the-graeffe-root-squaring-method-for-computing-the-zeros-of-a-polynomial/

Comment: How about a polynomial of the form $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^{2k}$ with $a_k>0$, $\forall k$?    This polynomial has no real root since $P(x)\geq a_0>0$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks @Emeu, interesting point, but apparently it goes in the opposite direction, right?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu, the input information is that $p$ indeed HAS all its roots real (for instance, it could be an orthogonal polynomial of even degree with respect to a symmetric weight on the real line). What I want to find is the polynomial vanishing at the positive ones.

Comment: In your degree 6 example, Andrei, $q(x)q(-x)\ne p(x)$, as the leading coefficient of $q(x)q(-x)$ will be $-1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ups. Right. Up to a change of sign.

Comment: So the problem is, given the values of elementary symmetric polynomials on $(\lambda_1, -\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n, -\lambda_n)$ find the values of the elementary symmetric polynomials on $(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$. As Erneu mentioned, this is the inverse of the Graeffe transform. There are simple explicit formulas for the direct Graeffe, but I don't see how to get formulas for the inverse...

Comment: When you multiply two polynomials, you essentially take the convolution of their coefficients. Thus, the Graeffe transform is like a convolution square. The inverse operation would be a convolution square root. In principle, it could be computed using a discrete Fourier transform (applying the fast Fourier transform would make this fairly efficient), then taking a square root pointwise in the Fourier domain, and finally transforming back. However, just as ordinary square roots are ambiguous up to a sign, you will have the same ambiguity at every point in the Fourier domain.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't think of how to fix the square root ambiguities in such a way as to satisfy the root positivity condition on $q(x)$.